# How to get out of nested loops in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, nested-loops

I want to get out of nested *while* in C to get back to main function. But I don't know how to do that. I mean, in my code, I want to use an instruction (except *goto* instruction because I want to make a procedural program) to break these two loops and get back to main function.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     float *Score = (float*) malloc (5 * sizeof (float));
     if (!Score)
     {
         printf("An error occurred while allocating memory.\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     char *Character = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char));
     if (!Character)
     {
        printf("An error occurred while allocating memory.\n");
        exit(2);
     }

     int Counter = 0; 
     while (Counter < 5)
    {
        printf("Enter your number %d : ", Counter + 1);
        scanf("%f", (Score + Counter));
        system("cls");

        if (Counter == 5 - 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        while (1)
        {
        printf("Do you want to continue? ");
        *Character = getch();
        system("cls");

        if (*Character == 'y')
            break;

        else if (*Character == 'n'); // I don't know what do I do here?

        else
        {
            printf("Press enter \'y\' or \'n\'\n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    Counter++;
}

Counter = 0;

while (Counter < 5)
{
    printf("%2.2f - ", *(Score + Counter));
    Counter++;
}

getch();

return 0;
}
```

I want to make procedural program and for this reason, I can't use *goto* instruction. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well you can set `Counter` to 4 or more before breaking from the first one.

Comment: Why can you not just return 'early'?

Comment: Never, never, never do `if (something); <<<<<`  That will be very difficult to maintain.  Put something instead, like `if (something) { /* empty */ }`  so everybody knows your intentions.  If you want an `if` statement with only an else part, just negate the condition in the parentheses and use the then part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add a break statement inside that condition in the nested while loop:

```
else if (*Character == 'n')
    break;
```

Then, after the end of that nested while-loop, add the same condition inside the enclosed while-loop to break out of it and get back to the main function:

```
if (*Character == 'n')
    break;
```

It will not have worked if `Character` was declared inside the nested loop.

Alternatively (a better way), in your case, you can also set the terminal condition of the enclosed while-loop inside that condition in the nested while-loop before breaking out of it. This will ensure that the enclosed loop will not iterate further:

```
else if (*Character == 'n')
{
    Counter = 5; // condition of the enclosed while-loop becomes false
    break;       // breaks out of the nested while-loop
    // altogether, you break out of both the loops
}
```

Comment: Really thank you. Your suggestion fixed my problem.

Comment: Are there any functions to do that in C programming language? Ardent Coder's solution fixed my problem.

Comment: @AmirMohsenGhasemi Maybe you are looking for [`setjmp` and `longjmp`](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-questions-setjmp-longjmp-functions-standard-library-uses/).